# DUPLICATE_VALUE:duplicate value found error on field that ISN'T marked is Unique?

Tags: duplicate-management, duplicate-value

I am trying to insert records via informatica, I am getting this error: "","false","false","DUPLICATE_VALUE:duplicate value found: customfield__C duplicates value on record with id: xxxxxxxxxxxx:--"

the thing is, I hard deleted all person accounts. That field is also NOT marked as unique.

has anyone ever seen this before? I have verified in the source file and there are no dupes. I am stuck.

Answer (score 3):

Did you check duplicate rules if there are any set up in your org?

Comment: This.  Also, deleted records stay in the recycle bin for 2 weeks, it might affect the duplicate rules?

Answer (score 1):

@TestMcTesterson This error indicates that you have the same record in the target Salesforce org. Also,this is a salesforce duplicate rule check error. So might want to see the Duplicate criteria for the target object and see if you can find the duplicate record in target Salesforce. And just to be sure check if you are pushing data to the same org which you deleted the records from. If you have more than one org, this seems to be confusion sometimes :)